# Fraction program not working

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for school that does multiplication and division with fractions. When I run the current code, multiplying the fractions 2/4 and 4/6 give me 0/1. When I individually tested the components for the numerator/denominator for the 2/4 and 4/6 fractions, it gave me back 0 1 0 1.

Here is the output and code, with code first.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;

class Fraction
{
    protected static int numerator, denominator;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Chp. 25 LAB 1");
        System.out.println();


//   main commands for testing first class Fraction

        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(2,4);
        System.out.println("numerator of fraction1 is  " + f1.getNum());
        System.out.println("denominator of fraction1 is  " + f1.getDen());
        f1.displayFraction();
        f1.alterFraction(3,6);
        f1.displayFraction();


//    main commands for testing second class FractionArithmetic

        f1 = new Fraction(2,4);
        Fraction f2 = new Fraction(4,6);

        FractionArithmetic f3 = new FractionArithmetic();
        f3.multFracts(f1, f2);
        f3.display();

        f3 = new FractionArithmetic();
        f3.divFracts(f1, f2);
        f3. display();


//    main commands for testing second class FractionOperations

        f1 = new Fraction(2,4);
        f2 = new Fraction(4,6);

        FractionOperations fract = new FractionOperations();
        fract.multFracts(f1, f2);
        fract.display();
        fract.reduce();
        fract.getFraction().displayFraction(); 

        fract = new FractionOperations();
        fract.divFracts(f1, f2);
        fract.display();
        fract.reduce();
        fract.getFraction().displayFraction();  
    }

    Fraction(int n, int d)
    {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;
    }
    public int getNum()
    {
        return numerator;
    }
    public int getDen()
    {
        return denominator;
    }
    public void alterFraction(int n, int d)
    {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;
    }
    public void displayFraction()
    {
        System.out.println("Fractioni = " + numerator + "/" + denominator);
    }
}

class FractionArithmetic
{   
    protected Fraction fraction;

    FractionArithmetic()
    {
        fraction = new Fraction(0, 1);
    }
    FractionArithmetic(int n, int d)
    {
        fraction = new Fraction(n, d);
    }
    public void multFracts(Fraction a, Fraction b)
    {
//      System.out.println(a.getNum() + " " + a.getDen() + " " + b.getNum() + " " + b.getDen());
        fraction.alterFraction(a.getNum() * b.getNum(), a.getDen() * b.getDen());
    }

    public void divFracts(Fraction a, Fraction b)
    {
        fraction.alterFraction(a.getNum() * b.getDen(), a.getDen() * b.getNum());
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("This is an unreduced fraction");
        fraction.displayFraction();
    }
    public Fraction getFraction()
    {
        return fraction;
    }
}

class FractionOperations extends FractionArithmetic
{
    Fraction reducedFraction;

    FractionOperations()
    {
        reducedFraction = new Fraction(0, 1);
    }
    FractionOperations(int n, int d)
    {
        super(n, d);
        reducedFraction = new Fraction(n, d);
    }
    public void reduce()
    {
        int gcf = getGCF(reducedFraction.numerator, reducedFraction.denominator);
        fraction.alterFraction(reducedFraction.numerator / gcf, reducedFraction.denominator / gcf);
    }   
    private static int getGCF(int a, int b)
    {
        int gcf = 1;
        a = Math.abs(a);
        b = Math.abs(b);
        if(a > b)
        {
            int dummy = b;
            b = a;
            a = dummy;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
        {
            if(b % i == 0 && a % i == 0)
                gcf = i;
        }
        return gcf;
    }
    public void display()
    {
        reducedFraction.displayFraction();
        fraction.displayFraction();
    }
    public Fraction getFraction()
    {
        return reducedFraction;
    }

}
```

> numerator of fraction1 is  2
>                 denominator of fraction1 is  4
>                 Fractioni = 2/4
>                 Fractioni = 3/6
>                 Fractioni = 0/1
>                 This is an unreduced fraction
>                 Fractioni = 0/0
>                 Fractioni = 0/1
>                 Fractioni = 0/1
>                 Fractioni = 0/1
>                 Fractioni = 0/0
>                 Fractioni = 0/0
>                 Fractioni = 0/0

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?  Seriously, you are learning to program, and one of the skills you need to learn is how to debug your own code.  If you don't try to do it, you won't learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, it's because your classes made it that it divides 2/4 by 3/6. I think that the programming is using numbers like 2/4 literally and not separately resulting in numbers such as 1 and 0 only.